# How do I use a button to activate a For loop to show each individual results per button click?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, button

I've been trying to figure this out for about 3 hours with multiple failures and my code end up just reverting back to this point.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learning</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function theMath(userOutput) {
      document.getElementById("userOutput").innerHTML = userOutput
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="userOutput"></p>

  <p> Counting from one to ten</p>
  <input type="button" id="btnOutput" value="Add a number!" />
  <p></p>
  <script>
    var strOutput = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      strOutput = " " + i;
      document.write(strOutput)
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Currently all the numbers are appearing under the button, What I need  to do however is that when I click on btnOutput, the first number of the for loop (0) is displayed. When I click on btnOutput again, the second number of the for loop is displayed (1). 
So every time I click on btnOutput the loop runs once, until it can't run any longer (when i=11)

Didn't mention: A for-loop is necessary for what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wish to append values on click, using a loop is not required. Just capture the event and append to the necessary element.

Also, since you are only trying to update text of element, you should try using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

- `innerHTML`: This will process passed string to HTML and then update html of the necessary element.
- `textContent`: This will not do any processing. It will just update the text content of element.

```js
// To avoid bleeding to global scope.
(function(){
  var count = 0;
  
  function theMath(userOutput) {
    document.getElementById("userOutput").textContent += userOutput
  }
  
  document.getElementById('btnOutput').addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(++count <= 10){
      theMath(count)
    }
  })
})()
```

```html
<p id="userOutput"></p>

<p> Counting from one to ten</p>
<input type="button" id="btnOutput" value="Add a number!" />
<p></p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use a for-loop in this instance, it's actually required to be in my code. I also need to use a button and function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a for-loop, just increment the number and display a new number.

```js
var i = 1;
var maxValue = 11;

document.getElementById("btnOutput").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (i < maxValue) {
    document.getElementById("userOutput").innerHTML += (i++) + "<br>";
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learning</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="userOutput"></p>

  <p> Counting from one to ten</p>
  <input type="button" id="btnOutput" value="Add a number!" />
  <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use a for-loop in this instance, it's actually required to be in my code. I also need to use a button and function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a for loop for this. Just assign a global variable and a global limit and then append incremented values to `innerHTML`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Learning</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    var maximum = 11;
    function addnum(){
        if (i<maximum) {
            document.getElementById("userOutput").innerHTML +=" "+i++;
        }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="userOutput"></p>

<p> Counting from one to ten</p>
<input type ="button"
        id = "btnOutput"
        onclick="addnum()"
        value = "Add a number!"/>
<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```